# Subclassing namedtuple with properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have some classes that have properties already defined and I am now looking for a way to pack data into a named tuple to interact with a database. I would like to have some of the properties (but not all) into the named tuple so that I can assign field names when retrieving data from the database.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import sqlite3

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'a, b')

class FooChild(Foo):

    def do_some_calculation(self):
        self.d = 2
        return self.d

    @property
    def b(self):
        return (self.a,)*2 + (self.d,)

    @property
    def c(self):
         return 'bar'

def retrieve_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/foodata')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT a, b FROM foos')
    for foo in map(Foo._make, cursor.fetchall()):
        print(foo.a, foo.b)


foo = Foo(11, ())
print(foo.a, foo.b, foo._asdict())
```

but `print(foo._asdict())` returns `OrderedDict([('a', 11), ('b', ())])` since the named tuple is immutable.

The 'b' property cannot be calculated during instantiation of the `namedtuple`.

Can somebody advise on the way to go in this situation ?

Comment: Why are you subclassing a `namedtuple` for this?

Comment: The idea of the `namedtuple` came from the eponym documentation. When I retrieve existing records in the database, I can give a name to fields directly as it is presently shown in retrieve_data. I am trying to have the same underlying structure between a newly created record and an existing one retrieved from the db. Is it the wrong approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the wrong approach. I know it's tempting to use this to have really short code but it just messes up other things. Keep it simple so that it's blatantly obvious to all readers (including future you) what's going on.

```
class FooV2(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    # c and d and stuff

def retrieve_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/foodata')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT a, b FROM foos')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        foo = FooV2(*row)
        print(foo.a, foo.b)
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming ! I have a feeling that the namedtuple structure will be handy for some other operations on the db. But reading your answer, I realised that if need be, I could just add a `as_namedtuple` method to `FooV2` which returns a representation of the record in the desired format. Cheers.